# In Javascript, what is the scope of variables used in setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, settimeout

I am using the following code in a function:

```
setTimeout("doSomething(var1)",10000);
```

But, I also have `var1` available as global variable. After 10000 milliseconds, will it call the local `var1` or the global `var1`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This:

```
setTimeout('doSomething(var1)', 10000);
```

will pass the global variable `var1`,

And this:

```
setTimeout(function() { doSomething(var1); }, 10000);
```

will pass the local variable `var1`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/EQMaz/

Answer (score 3):

It will pass the the global variable named `var1`.